# iOS 10 push notification previous payload structure not working which is working fine in iOS 9

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ios10, payload

My payload structure is :

```
{
aps =     {
    alert =         {
        body = "{\"list\":[{\"title\":\"title for push\",\"link\":\"https://www.google.com\"}]}";
        "loc-key" = "my push";
    };
    badge = 1;
};
```

}

but in lock screen banner text is showing as:

```
"{\"list\":[{\"title\":\"title for push\",\"link\":\"https://www.google.com\"}]}"
```

instead of :  my push

what is new change for payload structure, how to support array list?

Comment: check this [Link](https://blog.pusher.com/how-to-send-ios-10-notifications-using-the-push-notifications-api) , you will get your answer :)

Comment: Thanx for the link, the payload structure has been changed in ios10